# Hyperledger composer rest api add data not found in composer playground

Tags: rest, api, hyperledger-fabric

I have successfully generated composer rest api followed by instruction given by `https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html` finally am getting success message

```
Discovering types from business network definition ...
Discovered types from business network definition
Generating schemas for all types in business network definition ...
Generated schemas for all types in business network definition
Adding schemas for all types to Loopback ...
Added schemas for all types to Loopback
Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
```

and after am adding participant getting 200 response code in api , but the added data not displayed in composer playground, whats the issue in this? anyhelp appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your starting a business-network or upgrading a business-network. please ensure that your started network version same as composer-rest-server API version shown on `http://localhost:3000/explorer/`. If there is an issue then you can do `./stopFabric.sh`. and then start your business-network again.

Answer (score 0):

the playground is exactly what it says, a playground. It's a little environment to help you play with models, test them and create a bna from the result, not to deploy a fully working network.

However, if you do want to see some real data then you have to connect it to an actual network using a proper network card. If you use the web version then that's not connected to anything real.

So, connect the playground to the same network card you used to create the composer rest api and then you will be able to see something.

This being said, the best way to check your data actually exists on the ledger is to use the composer api you used to create you assets.

Every asset endpoint accepts all the verbs you need to work with. You used POST to create an asset, now use the GET method to check the data on the ledger. if you look at the swagger interface, you will see all endpoint, all verbs they accept and the data models required